# How to add error placement for dynamically added element with jquery validator rules?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements which will be added dynamically.So,I want to add validator rules for those each single element by element id.I could add rules but unable to place errorplacement for those particular elements.

```
for (var c = 0; c < imageSerialNums.length; c++) {
  $("#_cimageType"+ imageSerialNums[c]).rules("add", {
    required : true,
    messages : {}
  });
```

I want to add errorplacement for the element.

Comment: If you have dynamic elements it make much more sense to just apply `data` attributes on them which will work with jQuery.validate automatically.

Comment: It works.By default validator will append error messages to the respective element.But how do I need to append those error messages to another div?